# objective c undefined symbol compilation error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

Help please! my first program in objective c. Followed a tutorial word for word but it gives me this error that I don't know quite how to read for objective c.

SimpleCar.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface SimpleCar : NSObject {
    NSString* make;
    NSString* model;
    NSNumber* vin;
}

// set methods
- (void) setVin:   (NSNumber*)newVin;
- (void) setMake:  (NSString*)newMake;
- (void) setModel: (NSString*)newModel;

// convenience method
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake
        andModel: (NSString*)newModel;

// get methods
- (NSString*) make;
- (NSString*) model;
- (NSNumber*) vin;

@end
```

SimpleCar.m:

```
#import "SimpleCar.h"


@implementation SimpleCar
// set methods
- (void) setVin: (NSNumber*)newVin {

    [vin release];
    vin = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    vin = newVin;

}

- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake {

    [make release];
    make = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newMake];

}

- (void) setModel: (NSString*)newModel {

    [model release];
    model = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newModel];

}

// convenience method
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake
        andModel: (NSString*)newModel {

    // Reuse our methods from earlier
    [self setMake:newMake];
    [self setModel:newModel];

}

- (NSString*) make {
    return make;
}

- (NSString*) model {
    return model;
}

- (NSNumber*) vin {
    return vin;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [vin release];
    [make release];
    [model release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

CarApp.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleCar.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    SimpleCar *myCar = [[SimpleCar alloc] init];

    NSNumber *newVin = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];

    [myCar setVin:newVin];
    [myCar setMake:@"Honda" andModel:@"Civic"];

    NSLog(@"The car is: %@ %@", [myCar make], [myCar model]);
    NSLog(@"The vin is: %@", [myCar vin]);

    [myCar release];

  [pool drain];

  return 0;
}
```

compiler call:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc CarApp.m SimpleCar.m -g -m64
```

error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in ccR0Zlgm.o
      CFString in ccR0Zlgm.o
      CFString in ccR0Zlgm.o
      CFString in ccR0Zlgm.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in ccR0Zlgm.o
      -[SimpleCar setVin:] in ccJfVliU.o
      -[SimpleCar setMake:] in ccJfVliU.o
      -[SimpleCar setModel:] in ccJfVliU.o
      -[SimpleCar setMake:andModel:] in ccJfVliU.o
     (maybe you meant: l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release, l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc )
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      _main in ccR0Zlgm.o
  "_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in ccR0Zlgm.o
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in ccR0Zlgm.o
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in ccJfVliU.o
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in ccJfVliU.o
     (maybe you meant: l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release, l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ccR0Zlgm.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNumber", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ccR0Zlgm.o
      objc-class-ref in ccJfVliU.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[SimpleCar dealloc] in ccJfVliU.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SimpleCar in ccJfVliU.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ccJfVliU.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Add `-framework Foundation` to your gcc command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just created an Xcode Workspace without an Xcode project. Here's a project that you could use:

http://www.markdouma.com/developer/CarApp.zip

Generally, you just choose File > New Project to create a new project. You'd likely want a Foundation-based command-line program for this particular project.

Unfortunately, the tutorial didn't give the best implementation of the `SimpleCar` class. Below is one possible rewrite:

```
#import "SimpleCar.h"

@implementation SimpleCar

-(void) dealloc
{
    [vin release];
    [make release];
    [model release];
    [super dealloc];
}


// set methods
- (void) setVin: (NSNumber*)newVin {
    [newVin retain];
    [vin release];
    vin = newVin;
//    [vin release];
//    vin = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
//    vin = newVin;
}
```

The commented code above is the original code. It is both potentially dangerous and also leaks memory. The first line of the original code releases `vin` before doing anything else, which is potentially dangerous. For example, what if in your `CarApp.m` you did this:

```
NSNumber *vinValue = [car vin];
[car setVin:vin];
NSLog(@"car's vin == %@", [car vin]); // unpredictable results/crash
```

The original code would have released the existing `vin` value without bothering to make sure the value being passed in wasn't actually `vin` itself. By setting `vin = newVin`, it was setting `vin` to point to itself but after being released. Any subsequent attempts to send messages to `vin` would result in a crash or unpredictable results.

The original code also leaks memory. Instances of `NSNumber` are immutable, so creating a number through `alloc/init` doesn't really make much sense (since it will always be zero, and can never be changed). My replacement code first retains the value that is passed in, in case it happens to be `vin`. It then releases `vin` and then assigns `vin` to `newVin`.

The `setMake:` and `setModel:` methods are problematic for the same reasons.

```
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake {
    [newMake retain];
    [make release];
    make = newMake;
//    [make release];
//    make = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newMake];
}

- (void) setModel: (NSString*)newModel {
    [newModel retain];
    [model release];
    model = newModel;
//    [model release];
//    model = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newModel];
}

// convenience method
- (void) setMake: (NSString*)newMake
        andModel: (NSString*)newModel {
    // Reuse our methods from earlier
    [self setMake:newMake];
    [self setModel:newModel];
}

- (NSString*) make {
    return make;
}
- (NSString*) model {
    return model;
}
- (NSNumber*) vin {
    return vin;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6):

On your command line:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc CarApp.m SimpleCar.m -g -m64
```

you are not including the required frameworks for Cocoa and others.

My suggestion is building your application using Xcode, not the command line.

If you want and try from the command line, add all the frameworks you are using using the `-framework` linker switch, e.g.:

```
-framework Cocoa
```

but then you will also need another switch, identifying the SDK you are building against (I suppose), e.g.:

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

EDIT: if you want and try to use Xcode 4 to build your project, follow these steps:

1. open Xcode and create a new project: File > New > New Project;
2. choose a project type suitable to you (a Command Line Tool is appropriate);
3. add SimpleCar.c/h and CarApp.c to your project; remove the old main.c;

   (4. if you choose a project type other the Command Line Tool, instead of adding CarApp.c to the project, you should copy the content of your main() function into the `-awakeFromNib` function found in your ApplicationDelegate.)

Comment: your probably right. in the tutorial they compiled in xcode, though it does not want to give me the option to do this.

could you either advise me on why i can't compile/how to compile in xcode or what my command line call should look like.

thanks

Comment: What does "it does not want to give me the option" mean? It must work... :-)

Comment: i will try and show a screenshot, i have never really used xcode to compile but it would be nice to learn how, just a sec

Comment: screenshot:      

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JXUWLJtC9bofnlN_539DICJIgqoScqm-ISwu9GzGMZQ/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CNW1q7gD

Comment: My suggestion: forget the tutorial for a moment. Create a new Xcode project for an app and run it (it should compile and everything ok). Then, if this works, you can try and move your code to the new project (caring for the application delegate to be correctly set).

Comment: so now i have it running in xcode but i get the error:

        Thread1: program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: Please see my edit for more detailed instructions about the project. If problem persists, run you program in debug mode, so when crashing you will see exactly where.

Comment: You are awesome! IDK why it was so fkn hard to figure out how to compile an Ojbective C program without Xcode, but this did it (for anyone after me: `gcc hello-world.m -framework Foundation`)