# Disallow NSLog to be used

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

Is it possible to disallow the use of **NSLog**, so that it will come up as an error if used at compile time?
Ideally some sort of compiler flag with the name of the method that is disallowed?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @TRedman - I'm reading the book "Learning Core Audio" - Theres a footnote that says the author couldn't work out why his code wasn't running, he remmed out the NSLog's and found the code worked, it turned out it was a speed issue.

Comment: The question is interesting but the book author should have tried to find an actual problem at his code. For example messing comparison like this: `BOOL byes = YES;
    NSLog(@"%@", (byes = NO) ? @"N" : @"Y");` - note there's no comparison operator and `byes` is `NO` after this NSLog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you re-declare `NSLog` (and perhaps also `NSLogv`) as

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE;
void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE;
```

in your precompiled header file, you get a nice error message:

```
main.m:199:3: error: 'NSLog' is unavailable
                NSLog(@"%@", s1);
                ^
```

---

You can even provide a custom error message (found in [Messages on deprecated and unavailable Attributes](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#messages-on-deprecated-and-unavailable-attributes) of the Clang documentation):

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) __attribute__((unavailable("You should not do this!")));
```

```
main.m:202:3: error: 'NSLog' is unavailable: You should not do this!
                NSLog(@"%@", s1);
                ^
```

Comment: I'd like to give users of my code a reason as to why I have done this, is there anyway I can do this, or should I just put a comment above this line?

Answer (score 2):

In your prefix header:

```
#define NSLog(x, ...) (__please_dont_use_NSLog__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
 #ifdef DEBUG
 #   define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
 #else 
 #   define NSLog(...)
 #endif
```

The solution can be found here: [Enable and Disable NSLog in DEBUG mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552197/enable-and-disable-nslog-in-debug-mode)

Hope this helped!

Comment: That doesn't create an error if NSLog is used, it just silences NSLog output.