# iOS Build Script to Find and Replace Specific Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way in XCode to find and replace a string either at compile time or automatically?

I am using the DLog Macro

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

But sometimes I forget and use NSLog directly, but would want those NSLogs to be changed to DLogs.  Would a good solution be to use a build script?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you could use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069402/disallow-nslog-to-be-used to "forbid" the usage of NSLog in your source code.

Comment: The DLog is a wrapper for NSLog, so I still need to use NSLog in the macro

Comment: OK, yes of course (I had not noticed that due to the typo in the first version of the question.) - Perhaps one could solve that by defining DLog in terms of an utility functions DLogHelper, but I am not sure if it worth the hassle.

Comment: Yea thats my bad on the typo!  I was just looking for a quick solution, it might not be worth the hassle

Answer (score 0):

Define following NSLog macro in your .pch(Pre Compiled Header) file to replace iOS SDK's NSLog implementation.

```
define NSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```