# Xcode 6 + iOS 8 SDK but deploy on iOS 7 (UIWebKit & WKWebKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, swift, ios8

We are creating an app using Xcode 6 beta 5 + Swift on iOS 8 SDK. We'd like to deploy to iOS 7 as well. Is that possible? When we set the deployment target of the project to 7.0, we get compile time errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKPreferences", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo13WKPreferences in WebViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo9WKWebView in WebViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebViewConfiguration", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo22WKWebViewConfiguration in WebViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I believe that's because we are using `WKWebKit`, which is supported by iOS 8+ only. We are ok with using `UIWebKit` for iOS 7 but `WKWebKit` for iOS 8. How do we define that?

Our class definition looks like this...

```
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
   ...
}
```

and it's called by:

```
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as WebViewController
        presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I was thinking about using this fragment to call `presentViewController` but that doesn't solve the compile time issues. (`NSFoundationVersionNumber` doesn't solve compile time issues either)

```
    if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8.0) {

    } else {

    }
```

**UPDATE: kkoltzau has the correct answer. I'm adding some more info for others.**

First, go to your `Project`, click on `General`, scroll down to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, and add `WebKit.framework` as Optional. (I also did it for `UIKit.framework`) See screenshot:

[image]

As for my `WebViewController` class. It still imports `UIKit` and `WebKit`. but the `viewDidLoad()` sets the view based on kkoltzau's example. Then whenever I need to load/reload the web page, it checks for existence of `wkWebView`.

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors. Are you getting those from Xcode 6 or Xcode 5? BTW - Do not check the iOS version to determine what to do. Instead, check to see of a given class or method exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to check if WKWebView is available, and fall back to UIWebView if its not.

Make sure you weak link WebKit.framework (set to optional)

Objective-C:

```
WKWebView *wkWebView = nil;
UIWebView *uiWebView = nil;

Class wkWebViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"WKWebView");
if(wkWebViewClass) {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    // ...
    wkWebView = [[wkWebViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:config];
    [self.view addSubview:wkWebView];
}
else {
    uiWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:uiWebView];
}
```

Swift:

```
var wkWebView : WKWebView?
var uiWebView : UIWebView?

if NSClassFromString("WKWebView") {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    // ...
    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: config)
    self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)
}
else {
    uiWebView = UIWebView(frame: frame)
    self.view.addSubview(uiWebView)
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code:

Objective-C:

```
if(wkWebView) {
    // WKWebView specific code
}
else {
    // UIWebView specific code
}
```

Swift:

```
if let w=wkWebView {
    // WKWebView specific code
}
else if let w=uiWebView {
    // UIWebView specific code
}
```

Comment: None of this addresses the question which is about linker errors.

Comment: Thanks kkoltzau, let me try and report back. Interesting to know you can set class via 'NSClassFromString'

Comment: @rmaddy Weak linking to WebKit.framework, mentioned in the second sentence, covers the linker error.

Comment: Thanks kkoltzau about setting WebKit.framework to optional. I can't paste screenshot, but I'll do so as an answer for others.

Comment: My class also implements `WKNavigationDelegate`, including methods such as `    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation)` and `func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation)`. How do I include them in this example?

Comment: The app was able to compile, but at runtime, on an iOS 8 device, it's giving me an error that `wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: webViewWrapper.bounds, configuration: configuration)` resulted in nil, as no WKWebView was created. I can't tell if it's because `let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()` failed or not.

Comment: @Dean Regarding WKNavigationDelegate, just implement it as usual. I don't know why WKWebView would fail to create assuming WebKit.framework is properly linked.

Comment: @kkoltzau I understand why you would instantiate the WKWebView class from a string, but what is the reason for doing it with the WKWebViewConfiguration class as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support iOS7, you cannot use WebKit2 (`WK*`) classes, or you need to implement twice the logic, once for iOS8 using `WK*` and once using `UIWeb*`, and at runtime choose according to the operating system version.

Comment: That sentence 2 about "Make sure you weak link WebKit.framework (set to optional)" is super important.  I actually didn't even have WebKit.Framework listed so I needed to added it and set to Optional.