# UIWebView and WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I want to use WKWebView for IOS8 but also need compatibility for IOS7, I have seen the posts referring to using this code:

```
if ([WKWebView class]) {
// do new webview stuff
}
else {
// do old webview stuff
}
```

But not sure what I am doing wrong as the code below gives me a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help much appreciated, here is my code:

.h file:

```
#import "WebKit/WebKit.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *contentWebView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *contentWKWebView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize contentWebView;
@synthesize contentWKWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"LockBackground" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest * myNSURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:fileURL];
if ([WKWebView class]) {
    [contentWKWebView loadRequest:myNSURLRequest];
} else {
    [contentWebView loadRequest:myNSURLRequest];
}
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I guess you can't use IBOutlet in this case. If you add WKWebView to your xib or storyboard, the xib or storyboard can't be loaded below iOS 8.

Comment: How can a get around this please?

Comment: What about allocate one of webView via code. Not with xib or storyboard.

Comment: I only have the one webView with the 2 properties (not sure if this is good or not), should I have 2 webViews? Could you give example how to code it without IBOutlet? Thanks you.

Comment: `id webView;
    if([WKWebView class]) {
        webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    }
`
  like this.

Comment: Thanks, but I am new to this & not sure where I put this in my code plus what to delete from my code, do I delete my two properties & the UIWebView? Sorry!

Answer (score 50):

Go to your `Project`, click on `General`, scroll down to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, and add `WebKit.framework` as Optional. See here: [Xcode 6 + iOS 8 SDK but deploy on iOS 7 (UIWebKit & WKWebKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341238/xcode-6-ios-8-sdk-but-deploy-on-ios-7-uiwebkit-wkwebkit)

Comment: This is awesome answer :)

Comment: This should be considered as the right answer for this - Had this problem myself and fixed it quickly due to this answer. :)