# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7.3

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you link the WebKit framework to your project?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I imported `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`. But the minimum version of  Xcode deploy is 7.0.

Comment: I mean, did you: 1. Click on your project in Xcode 2. Select General 3. Locate "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" 4. Click the plus button at the bottom and select "WebKit.framework" 5. Click Add?

Comment: If you're minimum deployment target is iOS 7 you'll need to check which version of the OS the device is running. If the user is running iOS 7 you'll have to fall back to UIWebView. If they are using iOS 8 you can use WKWebView. This post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341238/xcode-6-ios-8-sdk-but-deploy-on-ios-7-uiwebkit-wkwebkit

Comment: @Jonathan You saved me . 1.I annotated these WKWebView code, that's running ok.

Comment: @Jonathan 2. I added WebKit.framework to the `Linked Frameworkds and Libraries`, that's ok too.

Comment: Finally I checked OS version of the project. Thank you ! @Jonathan

Comment: No Problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 42):

Just for reference:

Go to your Project -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries then add WebKit.framework

What you see here is that the WebKit framework is used but the actual binary is not getting linked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `@implementation` is absence. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561570/1067147) answer gives you more info.

Comment: where to check this @implementation ?

Comment: @AwaisMobeen Did you have a chance to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561570/1067147 ? Hope it explain the details

Answer (score 0):

Delete Derived Data -> Clean -> Build

Comment: Didn't work for me to deal with error undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Base64