# Swift Cocoapods with Objective-C files gives Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I have encountered the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VTapManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VTapManagerHelper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: it bit unclear. Tell us what's  your class  have, when this error is happening .

Comment: If you are using any pod, delete the pod folder and delete the derived data, clean and build again. If you getting same error , refer this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298322/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-objc-class-wkwebview-referenced

Comment: post some code, explain the steps you do to get that error, otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: Every good question has one of these: `?`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling dynamic frameworks? That worked for me.

To do it go to the podfile in your workspace and open it, then:

```
#Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
remove the hash here ->  #use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score -1):

It's minor, but don't forget to quit Xcode and run your ***yourProject.xcworkspace*** instead of ***yourProject.xcodeproj*** after installing CocoaPods