# How to add custom sound to ionic and capacitor push notifications using one signal

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal, capacitor

Is there anyone to help adding custom sound to ionic 5 and capacitor push notification with one signal, It works good with cordova but now I want to migrate to capacitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently integrated capacitor with one signal. You can try following the instructions(step 1 to 5) in this document: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup.

The following notes may also help you:

1. In step 2.1 "Import the OneSignal Cordova Plugin", run `npm install onesignal-cordova-plugin` and `npx cap sync` (commands in "Ionic Capacitor" tab). Cordova plugins installed in this step works all fine with Capacitor.
2. In step 5.4 "Add a Service Extension", there are two similar extensions in Xcode named "Notification **Content** Extension" and "Notification **Service** Extension", the correct one is "Notification **Service** Extension" (you will see `NotificationService.swift` if you select this extension, otherwise you will see `NotificationViewController.swift`).
3. In step 5.5.7 "You should now see all 3 frameworks", since we all use webview engine, we need to add "WebKit.framework", or your will fail and you might see the same error in this question: [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298322/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-objc-class-wkwebview-referenced).