# xcode 6.01 Mach - O linker error

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I have been trying to solve this problem for the past 2 days...

I am using the aubio.framework for an app I am trying to build and I keep getting the errors below
[image]

I tried all of the solutions I have found on SO but nothing worked.  The aubio.framework seems to be linked correctly and no other frameworks are linked (started a new project)

Please help me!

Comment: What other dependencies does `aubio.framework` have?

Comment: What are your selected architectures? See this answer, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22708072/2571566

Comment: I don't know a ton about `aubio`, but it may not be built for 64 bit architectures. I didn't dig very deeply to find out for sure. Have you tried building against 32 bit architectures instead?

Comment: @Kevin Hirch - arm64, armv7 and armv7s

Comment: Try to keep only armv7 and armv7s for the *Architectures* and armv7, armv7s and arm64 for the *Valid Architectures*.

Comment: @Aaron I haven't tried building for 32-bit. I bought a licence for a class that analyzes the BPM of a song from codecanyon. The class references aubio and it came with a project that runs on the architectures as above.   The project runs fine (tried going through all the build settings and make sure they are the same as my project)..that didn't fix it either

Comment: You should try that. Judging by the line "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" the project from which you got your screenshot is attempting to build against 64bit architectures and its failing and can't find any of the referenced symbols. This usually means they were built for a different architecture.

Comment: @Aaron The project I got the classes from has arm64, armv7 and armv7s as architectures in the build settings and works

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, you have to add following frameworks:

- Accelerate.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework

It seems that aubio doesn't work without it.