# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linker-errors, x86-64

I am getting this error when i run it on iPhone 5s simulator. It executes normally in lower versions of iPhone 5s. In my app i am using 3rd party lib **CompuwareUEM**. And also added all the files and lib file related to **CompuwareUEM** and it is compatible for 64bit.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CompuwareUEM", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SplashScreenViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CreateProfileViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MyTripsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in UserloginViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UEMAction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SplashScreenViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CreateProfileViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MyTripsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in UserloginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PickTripViewController.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can any one of you help me thanks in advance

Comment: try to delete the architectures one by one and test it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22708072/730701

Comment: That library does not support x86 cpu.

Comment: @TENSRI i tried in different ways that is deleting architectures one by one and tested my app i am getting the same linker error....

Comment: @user523234 can u plz tell me how do u know that library does not support x86 cpu. i check in [link](https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DOCDT60/iOS+ADK+Setup+and+Instrumentation#iOSADKSetupandInstrumentation-CompuwareUEM) this documentation in that they told it is support for 64 bit also

Answer (score -6, accepted):

issue resolved. The main problem is with the **CompuwareUEM** i totally remove that 3rd party library. Now it working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Run `lipo -info libCompuwareUEM.a` and check if there is x86_64

Check this [website](https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DOCDT60/iOS+ADK+Setup+and+Instrumentation), there is a detailed setup.

Comment: what is lipo -info  ?

Comment: lipo -info give you all the architectures supported by the binary, you have a static library like `CompuwareUEM.a` or you have the source code of the lib in your project ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean your complete build directory and derived data

open Xcode -> Product Clean and alt + product clean.

Answer (score 0):

The x86_64 architecture is used when you run a 64bit iPhone simulator! **DONT** mix it with arm64 which is the 64-bit Device architecture.

**The error clearly indicates that the library doesn't contain x86_64.**
[you could also check with lipo as said by las but the error is quiet clear]

Comment: if you have the project, build it for that, if you don't then ask for it

Comment: @downvoter :: please comment upon down voting so I can fix the post