# _OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper Error when implementing Keychain for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I have created a NSObject class KeychainItemWrapper.h / KeychainItemWrapper.m

**KeychainItemWrapper.h**

Code taken from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html

**KeychainItemWrapper.m**

Code taken from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

**Security.framework** already Added

App > Build Phases > **Compile Sources**: KeychainItemWrapper.m already present

**loginViewController.m**

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" accessGroup:nil];
```

I am getting 2 errors in above. Please can you help

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: Make sure you include `KeychainItemWrapper.m` in your target.