# C++ on Mac: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I get this error message when trying to build my program

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CustomerData::CustomerData()", referenced from:
      PreferredCustomer::PreferredCustomer() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How do i fix this error? I am running c++ on xcode.

Comment: is your CustomerData class defined and included in the project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: Yes, I have that along with a PersonData class and a PreferredCustomer class.

Comment: Error message says "use -v to see invocation" and I agree. Please *do* that and put the result in your question as extra details.

Comment: The linker isn't finding a _definition_ for the constructor `CustomerData::CustomerData()`, but the compiler did find a _delcaration_ for it (otherwise that would be your error). The most likely cause is that you haven't properly added a file to your project that contains definitions for the `CustomerData` class (or, if you have, that class is missing a definition for this particular constructor).

Comment: In general, you'd do yourself a huge favour to read up on exactly how you go from source code files to a complete compiled binary with C++. This knowledge is pretty essential for understanding errors like this one.

Comment: I had a problem with the default constructors. After fixing that problem it compiled fine. Thanks for the help.