# How to fix "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob, google-mobile-ads

After upgrade 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' (to 7.50.0 was 7.41.0), And run my code I got this Buildtime error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   “OBJC_CLASS$_GULSwizzler”

I tried to delete DerivedData file, upgrade cocoapods to the lates, clean build, same error

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: Isn't `GULSwizzler` part of the Firebase SDK?  If so you might need to update that too.

Comment: @NSR No, it is a different issue. thank you for reply :)

Comment: @trojanfoe You are right, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:

1. Update 'GoogleTagManager' (in general you need to update Firebase libraries).
2. Clean project & run.