# Xcode 10.3 build failure “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64”

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode, wrapper

I am trying to add a few C ++ files to Swift to make a bioinformatic tool prototype as part of my bachelor's thesis.

I am not a programmer and my studies are focused on biotechnology so this area is new to me, I have learned a lot but in this point I am completely stuck with the project, so I am looking for some help.

The error I am seeing is this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Aline_Wrapper::Aline_seq()", referenced from:
      -[Aline_W Aline_Full] in Aline_W.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The information I have read and tried to use to correct the error is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64).

I haven't been able to solve my problem using this information.

The project files that I have so far can be found [here](https://github.com/Facinatic/Align-sequences-in-Swift).

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at your code and there are few things you need to fix.

In MyMain.h, remove this line:

`#import "MyMain.cpp"`

You don't want to import a cpp file from a header file.

Add this line to MyMain.cpp.  You can add it after the #define, like this:

```
#define HERE std::cout << "At line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;

#import "MyMain.hpp"
```

You will now be able to build.

¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Thank you

But when making the corrections the same error still appears, will there be any configuration that is the difference?

The computer I use is borrowed so it takes more than a week to be able to review the corrections you mentioned in the code.

Comment: I'll submit a pull request with the changes I made to your project. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: I created a new git repo with the fixes. You can can find it here:  https://github.com/CogMachines/Align-sequences-in-Swift

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sorry for not thanking you before, I have been very busy with the project, but this helped me too much.