# unresolved symbols compiling code on mac os

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Mac OS Sierra
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
gcc version c++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_2) 9.2.0

I am trying to compile a test program that uses 
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binacpp
which uses microsoft's jsoncpp
https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp
and the openssl, curl, websockets, json libraries
i am running into a linking problem and it seems to
me that none of the symbols are resolved. cant figure out
why. Might be due to the ugly setup...

ugly setup:
- microsoft (jsoncpp) uses some tech that is not supported by llvm/clang
so it suggests using gcc and microsoft's packetmanager vcpkg.
with gcc the source compiled into a static library libjsoncpp.a which i
copied into my testprogramm's dir.
- compiled binacpp sources with gcc -c into objectfiles and used ar rcs libbinacpp *.o
to create another static library
- included include and lib dirs for openssl that is for some reason not found in the usual dirs, als well as the header files for libjsoncpp directly

whole command:

```
/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/c++-9 test.cpp libbinacpp.a libjsoncpp.a  
-I/Users/N/Downloads/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x64-osx/include
-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar  /openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib -lwebsockets -ljson -lcurl -lssl
```

the whole thing gives me lots of errors. Have no idea whats going wrong...
Any help appreciated.

Regards.

errors (small portion):

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   -"_EVP_sha256", referenced from:
>   - hmac_sha256[abi:cxx11](char const*, char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp_utils.o)
>   -  "_HMAC", referenced from:
>   -   hmac_sha256[abi:cxx11](char const*, char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp_utils.o)
>   -  "_SHA256_Final", referenced from:
>   -      sha256[abi:cxx11](char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp_utils.o)
>   -  "_SHA256_Init", referenced from:
>   -      sha256[abi:cxx11](char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp_utils.o)
>   -  "_SHA256_Update", referenced from:
>   -      sha256[abi:cxx11](char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp_utils.o)
>   -  "Json::Reader::parse(std::__cxx11::basic_string, -std::allocator > const&, Json::Value&,
>   bool)", referenced from:
>   -      BinaCPP::get_exchangeInfo(Json::Value&)       in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_serverTime(Json::Value&)       in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_allPrices(Json::Value&)       in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_allBookTickers(Json::Value&)       in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_depth(char const*, int, Json::Value&) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_aggTrades(char const*, int, long, long, int, Json::Value&) in -libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_24hr(char const*, Json::Value&) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      ...
>   -  "Json::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, Json::Value const&)", -referenced from:
>   -      _main in ccsPSRMm.o
>   -  "Json::Value::asStringabi:cxx11 const", referenced from:
>   -      BinaCPP::get_price(char const*) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -      BinaCPP::get_bookTicker(char const*, Json::Value&) in libbinacpp.a(binacpp.o)
>   -  "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator
>
> ... a lot more errors ....
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

it seems you just forgot to include your libraries in the project, please reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64), in case you are using Xcode it mentioned there by pictures how to do it.

Comment: not using xcode. please read the description of the problem. clang does not work on the code. i am using the command /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/c++-9 test.cpp libbinacpp.a libjsoncpp.a  
-I/Users/N/Downloads/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x64-osx/include
-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar  /openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib -lwebsockets -ljson -lcurl -lssl

Comment: which includes the libraries

Comment: symbol Json::Reader::parse() is not found during linking yet nm -gDC libjsoncpp.a shows it to be present. So it should be found. Have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: can you please write down the command you use to compile and link, or if you use an IDE not command line, tell me what IDE are you using?

Comment: dude its written there twice:

Comment: /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/c++-9 test.cpp libbinacpp.a libjsoncpp.a -I/Users/N/Downloads/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x64-osx/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include -L/usr/local/Cellar /openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib -lwebsockets -ljson -lcurl -lssl