# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTImageLoader"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After a lot of tests, my app won't run on **iOS**.

I have this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTImageLoader", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in libRCTImageResizer.a(RCTImageResizer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I use :

```
react: 16.12.0
react-native: 0.60.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the application on simulator and the libarary for RCTImageResizer is not available for simulator.

Can you please try to run it on device and check.

Comment: I try, but nothing change :/

Comment: May be, this link hepls you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: It finally work, I just delete everything, reinstall, and now it work !

Answer (score 3):

Hey i got a work around from another source [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-790498006)
I had to add in another framework called "RNCMaskedView" along with "RNSScreen"

```
pre_install do |installer|
 installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
   if pod.name.eql?('RNScreens') || pod.name.eql?('RNCMaskedView')
     def pod.build_type
       Pod::BuildType.static_library
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Instead you can try adding "RCTImageLoader" and follow up with other frameworks if the error is thrown from other frameworks

Just add the code at the bottom of the pod file
save it
Open terminal , go to the ios folder in your project and run "pod install"

Then come back to Xcode , clear your build cmd + shift + k
Give build

It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove "use_frameworks!" and use "cocoapods-user-defined-build-types" plugin in pod file, This plugin allows for a Podfile to specify how each Pod (or multiple Pods) should be built (ex. as a dynamic framework).

```
plugin 'cocoapods-user-defined-build-types'

enable_user_defined_build_types!

target "CoffeeApp" do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod "SwiftyJSON", :build_type => :dynamic_framework
```

https://github.com/joncardasis/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types

its work..

Comment: Describe in more detail why each step is needed.