# “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64” Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, undefined-symbol, buildbox

It's my first time with Xcode V11.3.1

I'm trying to compiling Buildbox 3 project on Xcode and i got error list,
36 error all starts with the following:

```
Undefined symbol:
```

and this message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoDidReward(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoDidReward:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::interstitialFailed(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::interstitialLoaded(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoFailed(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::bannerFailed(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoLoaded(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::bannerLoaded(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "_AOBSendInterstitialAdAttemptReport", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialImpression:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::networkFailed(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager networkFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "_AOBStartSessionReporting", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "PTModelGeneralSettings::shared()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] in GameViewController.o
  "PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoDidEnd(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoDidEnd:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTPAppDelegate::~PTPAppDelegate()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::Director::mainLoop()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController glkView:drawInRect:] in GameViewController.o
  "PTModelController::shared()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "PTModelController::loadDataForSplashScreen(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::Director::setViewport()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController glkView:drawInRect:] in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithEAGLView(void*)", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::FileUtils::addSearchPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "PTPAppDelegate::PTPAppDelegate()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::Application::run()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::Director::setOpenGLView(cocos2d::GLView*)", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "PTAdInvoker::interstitialClosed(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialClosed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "cocos2d::Director::startAnimation()", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in AppDelegate.o
  "cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
      cocos2d::FileUtils::sharedFileUtils() in GameViewController.o
  "cocos2d::Director::getInstance()", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController glkView:drawInRect:] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController touchesMoved:withEvent:] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController touchesEnded:withEvent:] in GameViewController.o
      ...
  "cocos2d::Application::getInstance()", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "PTModelController::clean()", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] in GameViewController.o
  "_AOBStopSessionReporting", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:] in AppDelegate.o
  "PTBaseModelGeneralSettings::orientation() const", referenced from:
      -[GameViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] in GameViewController.o
      -[GameViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] in GameViewController.o
  "PTAdInvoker::networkLoaded(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager networkLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "cocos2d::Director::stopAnimation()", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_AOBSendRewardedAdAttemptReport", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoImpression:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager rewardedVideoFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "_AOBSendBannerAdAttemptReport", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerImpression:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
  "PTAdInvoker::shared()", referenced from:
      -[AdIntegratorManager networkLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager networkFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager bannerFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialLoaded:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialFailed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      -[AdIntegratorManager interstitialClosed:] in AdIntegratorManager.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AdIntegratorInterface", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CustomAdIntegrator.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and some of these error messages:

```
Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoDidReward(char const*, bool)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::interstitialFailed(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::interstitialLoaded(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoFailed(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::bannerFailed(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::bannerFailed(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::rewardedVideoLoaded(char const*)

Undefined symbol: PTAdInvoker::networkFailed(char const*)
```

After a long search I found a solution  using the following

*

> project >> Build setting >> Apple clang - Language - C++ >> Change C++
>   Standard Library to libstdc++ (GNY C++ Standard Library )

*

it works and all above errors is gone BUT....
I got new following error: on this code

```
#include <stack>            'stack' file not found
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
```

error under **"Lexical or Preprocessor issue"**
on **CCDirector.h**

and when i remove " #include stack " line, i got new error:

```
 'thread' file not found
```

And so on.....

Therefore, I think this solution is ineffective for me
or can i solve **'stack' file not found** ???

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are including the library wrong.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? http://help.buildbox.com/en/articles/3436281-xcode-ios-installation-instructions-for-ironsource-with-mediation-for-admob-applovin-and-unity-ads-game-analytics-and-tenjin-part-1

Comment: @HWilmer not this one,
i will check it out, maybe i missed something...

thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a long time but anyway,

this solution >>>

> project >> Build setting >> Apple clang - Language - C++ >> Change C++
> Standard Library to libstdc++ (GNY C++ Standard Library )

**will lead to noting,**

the issue from the beginning is there are some libraries and SDKs inside this project doesn't support Xcode simulators (i have asked the SDK owner support about that)

and when I have built my app and test it on a real device, everything works fine.

that was my situation, if you faced this issue when building your project not when run it on simulators, try the above solution or check this post

[Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)