# XCODE : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm struggling with Xcode since one week (since the upgrade)

I have this error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" on xcode.

can you help me to fixed this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64