# Xcode Build Failure on Archive, but not on Run with ResearchKit

Tags: swift, xcode, researchkit

I'm trying to build a project that has ResearchKit in it, and whenever I build and run on a physical device (or the simulator, for that matter) it works fine. But when I attempt to Archive it, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKVisualConsentStep", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in InformedConsent.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I followed the installation guidelines on the ResearchKit GitHub, and made sure to check that researchKit.framework was under the Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content section as well as the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the build phases tab (as was described in this link as well as a couple others: [Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)) but still nothing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or another setting I might be able to change?

---

UPDATE:

I noticed that the element that was throwing the error - ORKVisualConsentStep - was deprecated a few iOS versions ago. So by taking that out, I was able to get the project to archive.

I didn't want to put this as the accepted answer, though, because I wanted to see if there was a better solution than just deleting code.

---

Thanks for your help!