# Upgrading React Native version give me "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: react-native

I am trying to upgrade my react-native version from 63 to 67.4 and I have issues for the iOS part.

I have done `bundle install` `yarn upgrade` `cd iOS && pod install` and this is the issue I have after changing iOS deployment target from 10.0 to 11.0 as suggested in the react-native upgrade helper.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_BVLinearGradientManager in BVLinearGradientManager.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BVLinearGradientManager in BVLinearGradientManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_BVLinearGradient in BVLinearGradient.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BVLinearGradient in BVLinearGradient.o
  "_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
      +[BVLinearGradientManager load] in BVLinearGradientManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTConvert", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BVLinearGradient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After fixing this error by adding React-Core to the linked binary with librairies in the Build Phases. I have a second error which I don't know if it is linked to the previous fix or from what it is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MQTTFlow in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSSQLiteAnalyzeOption", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MQTTFlow in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
  "_NSInMemoryStoreType", referenced from:
      -[MQTTCoreDataPersistence createPersistentStoreCoordinator] in libNAOSDK.a(MQTTCoreDataPersistence.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And this is the dependencies I have in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.16.7",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-batch": "6.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "3.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "14.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.1.1",
    "@zsajjad/react-native-heading": "git+https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-heading.git",
    "buffer": "6.0.3",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0",
    "i18next": "21.6.14",
    "memoize-one": "6.0.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "11.16.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
    "react-native-autolink": "4.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "4.2.1",
    "react-native-cardiweb-polestar": "0.5.7",
    "react-native-contacts": "7.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "3.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.5.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.37.3",
    "react-native-image-progress": "1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "13.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "5.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.5.0",
    "react-native-root-modal": "5.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "3.11.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-swipeable": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "3.0.16",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "5.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.17.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "0.5.16",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0"
  },
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64 see this link

Comment: @Ajith I don't know what library should be added for `OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStore`